# Pandas read_html only finds header of a html table

Tags: python, html, pandas, html-table, html-parsing

I have this table: 
[image]

I parsed it using pandas:

```
s = '<table id="datatable"><tr><th onclick="sortTable(0)">Gene locus</th><th onclick="sortTable(1)">Organism</th><th onclick="sortTable(2)">Found in</th><th onclick="sortTable(3)">Gene name</th><th onclick="sortTable(4)">AA mutation</th><th onclick="sortTable(5)">Drug</th><th onclick="sortTable(6)">Tandem repeat name</th><th onclick="sortTable(7)">Tandem repeat sequence</th><th onclick="sortTable(8)">Reference</th></tr><td>ASPNIDRAFT_55947</td><td>Aspergillus niger</td><td>Animal - Human</td><td>CYP51a</td><td>R228Q </td><td>Posaconazole</td><td></td><td><div style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 250px;"></div></td><td><a href="http://jcm.asm.org/content/54/9/2365.full">10.1128/JCM.01075-16</a></td></tr></table>'
table = pandas.read_html(s)[0]
print(table)
```

However this gives me:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Gene locus, Organism, Found in, Gene name, AA mutation, Drug, Tandem repeat name, Tandem repeat sequence, Reference]
Index: []
```

There is clearly a filled row (`<tr>...`) beneath the header (`<th>..`) so I can't figure out where it goes wrong, and more importantly how I can read the table properly.

(P.s. I can't acces Imgur from the country I'm in now, so feel free to change it if the link is inappropriate or tell me how I can change it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `<tr>` before the first `<td>`

Here is the correct string,

```
s = '<table id="datatable"><tr><th onclick="sortTable(0)">Gene locus</th><th onclick="sortTable(1)">Organism</th><th onclick="sortTable(2)">Found in</th><th onclick="sortTable(3)">Gene name</th><th onclick="sortTable(4)">AA mutation</th><th onclick="sortTable(5)">Drug</th><th onclick="sortTable(6)">Tandem repeat name</th><th onclick="sortTable(7)">Tandem repeat sequence</th><th onclick="sortTable(8)">Reference</th></tr><tr><td>ASPNIDRAFT_55947</td><td>Aspergillus niger</td><td>Animal - Human</td><td>CYP51a</td><td>R228Q </td><td>Posaconazole</td><td></td><td><div style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 250px;"></div></td><td><a href="http://jcm.asm.org/content/54/9/2365.full">10.1128/JCM.01075-16</a></td></tr></table>'
```

It works now.

Comment: Thankyou that fixed it! I used `s = s.replace("<td>", "<tr><td>", 1)` to replace if for all pages I parse

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

```
s = '<table id="datatable"><tr><th onclick="sortTable(0)">Gene locus</th><th onclick="sortTable(1)">Organism</th><th onclick="sortTable(2)">Found in</th><th onclick="sortTable(3)">Gene name</th><th onclick="sortTable(4)">AA mutation</th><th onclick="sortTable(5)">Drug</th><th onclick="sortTable(6)">Tandem repeat name</th><th onclick="sortTable(7)">Tandem repeat sequence</th><th onclick="sortTable(8)">Reference</th></tr><tr><td>ASPNIDRAFT_55947</td><td>Aspergillus niger</td><td>Animal - Human</td><td>CYP51a</td><td>R228Q </td><td>Posaconazole</td><td></td><td><div style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 250px;"></div></td><td><a href="http://jcm.asm.org/content/54/9/2365.full">10.1128/JCM.01075-16</a></td></tr></table>'
table = pandas.read_html(s)[0]
print(table)
```

You were missing a `<tr>` tag after first `</tr>` tag.

Output:

> ```
>          Gene locus  ...             Reference
> 0  ASPNIDRAFT_55947  ...  10.1128/JCM.01075-16
>
> [1 rows x 9 columns]
> ```